# Highslide JS doesn't work when using remote hosted images

Tags: highslide

Highslide JS doesn't work when using remote hosted images

Can you help me with this?

**Example 1:**  [Doesnt work here- gallery is ok, but no zooming available images are remote uploaded](http://filmisub.com/ekshani/338-moonraker-007-muunreikar-1979.html)

**Example 2:** [Works here!- zooming is ok,Images are stored localy on server](http://filmisub.com/komedii/321-the-incredible-burt-wonderstone-fenomenalnia-burt-uondarstoun-2013.html)

Comment: On the "doesn't work" page, highslide.js isn't being loaded anywhere.

Comment: thats the problem, why when adding remote images to gallery script doesnt work and highslide.js isnt loaded at all?

Comment: now i have manually added code for highslide.js in header but script doesnt work again.

Comment: Sorry, I can't sort through the mess of your code. On the IBW page, you're loading highslide.js twice, which you should NEVER do. On the Moonraker page, you're loading it, but not doing any of its configuration settings.

Comment: its loaded twice because i have added manually. When uploading images on server highslide.js is loaded auto, and when  remote images are used this doesnt happen, dont why so i a have added code, anyway  doesnt work too.

Answer (score 0):

Highslide JS does work with externally hosted images. A quick demo - the web page is on a server in Sweden. The images are on a server in Texas:

http://earlyout.jalbum.net/externalImages

Comment: Your "Moonraker" page never calls highslide.js, and never sets up the Highslide variables (hs.graphicsDir, etc.) - that entire chunk of code is simply not present.

Comment: the difference between calling highslide.js (all other pages) and not calling (Moonraker) occures when using remote images- thats i can tell. may be other code outside Highslide JS conflicts with remote images usage.

Comment: You misunderstand. There simply is no line of code on the Moonraker page that would EVER load highslide.js, and even if there were, there are no lines of code on that page that would EVER configure it for proper functioning.

Comment: yes but on other pages there is such code that loads highslide.js and works, whats the difference between Moonraker and the other pages- on Moonraker i use remote images and on other pages images are on server uploaded

Comment: One more time.... The Moonraker page doesn't include any of the code needed to make Highslide work. It has nothing to do with where the images are being called from.

Comment: it doesnt work even when i manually added the code to the header